# ? super Type Java Generics

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, super

I have Java 8 generics question .

I have following class hierarchy:

```
Employee is base class
Manager extends Employee
Executive extends Manager
```

The following line (1) does not compile:

```
(1) List<? super Manager> foos1 = new ArrayList<Executive>(); // error
```

The below lines 2 and 3 compile ok:

```
(2) List<? super Manager> foos2 = new ArrayList<Manager>();   
(3) List<? super Manager> foos3 = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

however, even though I can still add Executive like so:

```
(4) foos2.add(new Manager("Manager!",123));
(5) foos3.add(new Executive("Executive!",1.0,2));
```

Please explain the logic why I can not assign variable

```
<? super Manager> = ArrayList<Executive>
```

where Executive is a super of Manager but I can still add Executive object to the array list?

many thanks!

Comment: the so called duplicate (i.e. PECS) does not answer my question.

Comment: I think it does.. but thats my opinion.. Well, Ive reopened your question :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner - Apparently that post doesn't answer the OPs question

Comment: @TheLostMind Sure, I understand you closed the question and reopened it. The link is useful to readers that reach here, though.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner - Yes it is :)

Answer (score 4):

`Executive` is a ***sub*** class of `Manager`, not a superclass.

The other two work because `Employee` is a superclass of Manager and type bounds are inclusive (i.e. the class itself or any of its superclasses), so `Manager` fits in the bounds.

Comment: I'm betting the OP got confused because this is the opposite of the way the hierarchy works in business.  Although of course the hierarchy in his code is the way things _should_ be ... (http://dilbert.com/strip/1994-01-04)

Answer (score 4):

```
List<? super Manager> foos1 = new ArrayList<Executive>(); // error
```

`? super SomeClass` 
What this means is that you can create a new List of a class which is a Super-class of SomeClass. Since `Executive` is NOT a super-class of Manager, you can't assign `List<? super Manager> foos1 = new ArrayList<Executive>();`

Next, why  `foos3.add(new Executive("Executive!",1.0,2));` works? 
Now, `List<? super Manager> foos3 = new ArrayList<Employee>();` can accept any `Manager` instance. Turns out `Executive` is a `Manager`, so you can add an `Executive` to the `List`